Deploy Angular 17 SSR in Azure Web App Node.JS 18
I am currently having a very frustrating situation regarding the deployment of an Angular 17 server side rendering app into Web App in Azure Node.JS v18. For some reason it takes enormous amount of time on building and finally it fails, and I do not really understand how this should actually be.
Does anyone have ever deployed Angular 17 SSR into Azure successfully?
Unfortunately Angular documentation does not provide any information, either Azure, and I am not sure if I might be doing something wrong.
The error displayed after 5h is:
Run npm run build

> myApp@0.0.0 build
> ng build

- Building...

Error: The operation was canceled.

I tried to deploy via Github actions, getting a web app in Azure Node.js v18
"prerender": true,
"aot": true,



"budgets": [
  {
    "type": "initial",
    "maximumWarning": "500kb",
    "maximumError": "1.1mb"
  },
  {
    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
    "maximumWarning": "2kb",
    "maximumError": "4kb"
  }
],



Dependencies


"@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^17.3.10",
"@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
"@angular/ssr": "^17.3.6",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.2.0",
"@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
"angular-oauth2-oidc": "^17.0.2",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"marked": "^12.0.2",
"ngx-localstorage": "^6.0.0",
"ngx-markdown": "^17.2.1",
"ngx-sonner": "^1.0.0",
"prismjs": "^1.29.0",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"stackedit-js": "^1.0.7",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.14.3"



I am suspecting that maybe dynamic routes are affecting somehow
{
    path: 'article/:id/:slug',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import(
        './modules/posts/components/article-container/article-container.component'
      ).then((c) => c.ArticleContainerComponent),
    resolve: {
      data: SingleArticleResolver,
    },
    data: { prerender: false},
  },

can somebody please help out with this situation?
Thanks in advance.

"it fails"? Could you elaborate? Do you see any error message? If yes, please add it to your question.

@JSONDerulo I just updated the question with the error

Can you try running ng build --verbose to see where exactly the build gets stuck?

@JSONDerulo here is the gits https://gist.github.com/HeyBaldur/c2b0a47165b4020aae2696ba256a01cb
I can see that locally is the same problem. It got stuck as in Github Actions.

You might want to disable pre-rendering if you don't need it.

@MatthieuRiegler if I disabled pre-rendering the SEO is crashed and it does not work at all :( it is required, unless there is another alternative.

If you enable SSR, you don't need pre-rendering. The result will be the same.

@MatthieuRiegler I created SSR Angular 17 app from scratch, what do you mean by enable SSR?

I am suspecting that the problem is related to the dynamic routes, I made some tests without any dynamic routes and it works perfectly, but when there are dynamic routes nothing works.

Do you want SSR or SSG ? The former generates pages at runtime, the latter at build time. Both can be exclusive, so if you want SSR, you might not need SSG.

Which one is better for SEO purposes only?

Both should result in similar results in terms of SEO. Prerender is less dynamic as it relies on informations available at build time.

@HeyBaldur If possible, share your GitHub repository?

@HeyBaldur Share complete package.json file.

@AsleshaKantamsetti it is not possible to share the repo.

@HeyBaldur Please share your GitHub Workflow file.

@HeyBaldur Shar complete package.json file.
